# How to do line segmentation in extracting text from image?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am python beginner. Now I'm working on a project of Cambodian License plate number recognition. On the plate, there are three lines of text. First line, it is a province/city written in Cambodian language. The second, vehicle number and the third is also a province/city written in Latin. I want to separate and draw lines on the image. Can anyone guide me how to separate the lines from the plate number image ? I do appreciate all your ideas [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? This question is very broad, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can check for EAST text detection method in opencv, not sure about Cambodian language but at least it should identify last two rows. Once you try that and stuck anywhere update your question accordingly.

Comment: I read some researches and I found the projection profile method. I tried to comprehend that but I did not quite understand. I read the 'Thai License plate number detection' but it did not really talk much in detail.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327298216_Thai_License_Plate_Recognition_Based_on_Deep_Learning

Comment: in this research, it states that "each license plate image was then segmented into 3 parts according to its triple-line type of license plate by using SSD. The SSD processes have been carried out separately for Inception-v3 and MobileNets." But i do not know how to implement it